# Making row values into column values SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

SQL Returns the following results from table

```
+-----+----+-----+----+----+
| PID | PY | QTY | TS | TM |
+-----+----+-----+----+----+
|  99 | CT |   1 |  1 |  6 |
|  99 | E  |   3 |  1 |  5 |
|  99 | GR |   4 |  1 |  6 |
+-----+----+-----+----+----+
```

I would like to use PIVOT (if even possible) to make the results like so:

```
+-----+----+-----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| PID | PY | QTY | TS | TM | PY | QTY  |  TS  |  TM  |  PY  | QTY  |  TS  |  TM  |
+-----+----+-----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  99 | CT |   1 |  1 |  6 | E    | 3    | 1    | 5    | GR   | 4    | 1    | 6    |
| 100 | V  |   6 |  6 |  2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-----+----+-----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: @ughai any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated coz I'm newbie to sql pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a limited number of values, then the easiest way to get the result would be to use an aggregate function with some CASE expressions.

```
select 
  pid,
  PY1 = max(case when py = 'CT' then PY end),
  QTY1 = max(case when py = 'CT' then QTY else 0 end),
  TS1 = max(case when py = 'CT' then TS else 0 end),
  TM1 = max(case when py = 'CT' then TM else 0 end),
  PY2 = max(case when py = 'E' then PY end),
  QTY2 = max(case when py = 'E' then QTY else 0 end),
  TS2 = max(case when py = 'E' then TS else 0 end),
  TM2 = max(case when py = 'E' then TM else 0 end),
  PY3 = max(case when py = 'GR' then PY end),
  QTY3 = max(case when py = 'GR' then QTY else 0 end),
  TS3 = max(case when py = 'GR' then TS else 0 end),
  TM3 = max(case when py = 'GR' then TM else 0 end),
  PY4 = max(case when py = 'V' then PY end),
  QTY4 = max(case when py = 'V' then QTY else 0 end),
  TS4 = max(case when py = 'V' then TS else 0 end),
  TM4 = max(case when py = 'V' then TM else 0 end)
from yourtable
group by pid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c6cf/1). You can use PIVOT to get the result but it will be messier because you'll need to unpivot the multiple columns first, and then pivot them.  If you want to use the pivot function, then you'd have to do the following.

First, use `row_number()` to assign a unique value to each `pid` combination:

```
select pid, py, qty, ts, tm,
  rn = row_number() over(partition by pid order by pid)
from yourtable
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c6cf/6)

Then unpivot the multiple columns `py`, `qty`, `ts` and `tm`:

```
select 
  pid, 
  new_col = col + cast(rn as varchar(10)),  
  val
from
(
  select pid, py, qty, ts, tm,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by pid order by pid)
  from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'py', py union all
  select 'qty', cast(qty as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'ts', cast(ts as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'tm', cast(tm as varchar(10))
) c (col, val)
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c6cf/5)

I used `CROSS APPLY` to convert the multiple columns into multiple rows. Finally, you'll pivot the `new_col` and their corresponding values:

```
select pid,
    py1, qty1, ts1, tm1, py2, qty2, ts2, tm2,
    py3, qty3, ts3, tm3, py4, qty4, ts4, tm4
from
(
  select 
    pid, 
    new_col = col + cast(rn as varchar(10)),  
    val
  from
  (
    select pid, py, qty, ts, tm,
      rn = row_number() over(partition by pid order by pid)
    from yourtable
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'py', py union all
    select 'qty', cast(qty as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'ts', cast(ts as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'tm', cast(tm as varchar(10))
  ) c (col, val)
) src
pivot
(
    max(val)
    for new_col in (py1, qty1, ts1, tm1, py2, qty2, ts2, tm2,
                    py3, qty3, ts3, tm3, py4, qty4, ts4, tm4)
) piv;
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c6cf/8)

Both versions will give the same final result.

```
| pid | py1 | qty1 | ts1 | tm1 | py2 | qty2 | ts2 | tm2 | py3 | qty3 | ts3 | tm3 |    py4 |   qty4 |    ts4 |    tm4 |
|-----|-----|------|-----|-----|-----|------|-----|-----|-----|------|-----|-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  99 |  CT |    1 |   1 |   6 |   E |    3 |   1 |   5 |  GR |    4 |   1 |   6 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, that' what I seek .